# Why the 'prompt' is coming again & again?

Tags: javascript, html, function, if-statement, conditional-statements

**Edit:** This question has a silly mistake which I didn't check before, and now I am not able to **delete** this question, **PLEASE IGNORE.**

I've created a simple website following a tutorial, which mainly does two very simple things

1). Changes the image whenever we click on it.

2). Asks every time, the user for their Name.

**HTML**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>The Great Himalayas</title>
  
    <link href="styles/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Josefin+Slab&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Himalayas</h1>

    <img src="images/himalayas.jpg" alt="Image showing himalayan mountains">
    <p>Image by <a href="https://pixabay.com/users/12019-12019/?utm_source=link-attribution&amp;utm_medium=referral&amp;utm_campaign=image&amp;utm_content=81244">David Mark</a> from <a href="https://pixabay.com/?utm_source=link-attribution&amp;utm_medium=referral&amp;utm_campaign=image&amp;utm_content=81244">Pixabay</a></p>
    
    <p>The majestic Himalayas: An escape to the heaven, the dwelling place of our dreams.
      The ice covered rock sphears pointing to the ultimate stage of consciousness,
      filled with the experience of millions of years, giving us direction to the expanding universe,
      where one seeks truth, because of the maze-valleys leading us to the exceptional realities,
      we don't know whether they are gigantic or atomic since everything is insignificant in the great workings of the universe,
      All we can do is just breathe....
    </p>

    <p>What you want:</p>
    <ul>
      <li>Mindset</li>
      <li>Will Power</li>
      <li>Courage</li>
      <li>Motivation</li>
    </ul>

    <p>What you will get!</p>
    <ol>
      <li>Experience</li>
      <li>Learnings</li>
      <li>Hope</li>
      <li>Beauty</li>
    </ol>

    <a href="https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/earth-and-planetary-sciences/himalayas">Learn more about the "almighty's home" here</a>
    <button>Change User</button>
    <script src="scripts/main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
html {
  font-size: 10px; 
  font-family: 'Josefin Slab', serif; 
  background-color: #A8D0FF;
}

img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
  
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 80px;
  text-align: center;

  margin: 0;
  padding: 30px 0;
  color: #A8D0FF;
  text-shadow: 3px 3px 1px black;
}

p,li,a {
  font-size: 16px; 
  line-height: 1.5;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

body {
  width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #CBE3FF;
  padding: 0 15px 20px 15px;
  border: 5px solid #5CB6D5;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
let himImg = document.querySelector("img") ;

himImg.onclick = function() {
    let himSrc = himImg.getAttribute("src");
    if (himSrc === "images/himalayas.jpg")
        {
            himImg.setAttribute("src","images/himalayas-2.jpg");
        }
    else
        {
            himImg.setAttribute("src","images/himalayas.jpg");
        }
}

let userButton = document.querySelector("button");
let userHeading = document.querySelector("h1");

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
setUserName();
if(!localStorage.getItem("Name")) {
    setUserName();                                     
} 
else {
    let storedName = localStorage.getItem("Name");                                                  
    userHeading.textContent = "Go to the Himalayas' " + storedName + " :)";
}
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

function setUserName() {
    let myName = prompt("Plese enter your Name :)");
    localStorage.setItem("Name",myName);
    userHeading.textContent = "Go to the Himalayas' " + myName + " :)";
}
```

but in the JavaScript code, we simply do not call the **setUserName()** function, instead, it runs through a **conditional statement  (if-else)** (as followed through the tutorial).

```
setUserName();
if(!localStorage.getItem("Name")) {
    setUserName();                                    
} 
else {
    let storedName = localStorage.getItem("Name");                                                        
    userHeading.textContent = "Go to the Himalayas' " + storedName + " :)";
}
```

- I think the function of the **conditional statement** is to only run the **setUserName()** function **( if() )** when the **Name** data type does not exist and **else** when it exists (that is, the user set a user name during a previous visit), we retrieve the stored name using **getItem()** and set the **textContent** of the heading to a string, plus the user's name *
  *But every time I refresh the page it again displays the **prompt**, why? (it may should not as I have already done it previously) I'm stuck, please Help!*

Comment: You call `setUserName()` in the line before the `if(!localStorage.getItem("Name"))`

Comment: I'm so sorry, it was an error from my side, I didn't check it 
I will delete this question ASAP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but in the JavaScript code, we simply do not call the setUserName()
> function, instead, it runs through a conditional statement (if-else)
> (as followed through the tutorial).

But you do call it:

```
setUserName(); // <--- Here you call it before the if / else
if(!localStorage.getItem("Name")) {
    setUserName();                                    
}
```

Comment: I'm so sorry, it was an error from my side, I didn't check it

Comment: No need to be sorry :)